# cannot drop type "enum_TableName_column" because other objects depend on it. (PostgreSQL, Sequelize, Node.js)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, dependencies, sequelize.js

Using [Sequelize.js](http://sequelizejs.com), Node.js, and PostgreSQL.

When trying to force sync the models to the database (`drop everything, create everything`) I receive errors on the types created for any enum fields.

Example:

```
{ 
    [error: cannot drop type "enum_Availabilities_status" because other objects depend on it]
    length: 304,
    name: 'error',
    severity: 'ERROR',
    code: '2BP01',
    detail: 'table "Availabilities" column status depends on type "enum_Availabilities_status"',
    hint: 'Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.',
    position: undefined,
    internalPosition: undefined,
    internalQuery: undefined,
    where: undefined,
    file: 'src\\backend\\catalog\\dependency.c',
    line: '951',
    routine: 'reportDependentObjects' 
}
```

This appears after executing:

```
sequelize.sync({ force: true })
```

Any suggestions on how to get around this?

Comment: Sounds like things are being dropped in the wrong order?  Types should *definitely* be dropped last.

Comment: Makes sense to me, that one line I posted is literally everything that handles it though and sequelize is just a npm library we're using so maybe it's something we need to address with them?

Comment: Yup, sounds like a bug in that library..  I doubt there's anything you can do to make Postgres wipe out all dependencies on an enum automatically..

Answer (score 6):

I can't tell you how the ORM does things, but you could force this first by dropping to SQL and issuing the following:

```
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS enum_Availabilities_status CASCADE;
```

My guess is that the CASCADE is missing from the SQL call.  Then resync.

Please try this on a copy of your database first.  I am not 100% sure what will happen if you already have a type in the column.

Comment: Although I understand cascade in theory should cascade the type to a replacement type, but still is it the behaviour if I'm not being wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. First drop all the tables that uses the enum. Then drop the enum.

```
await queryInterface.dropTable('Attachments');
await queryInterface.sequelize.query('DROP TYPE "enum_Attachments_parent_type";');
```